# Logstash|exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError",:message=>"Expected one of [ \\t\\r\\n], \"#\", \"=>\" at line 22, column 20

Tags: google-bigquery, configuration, logstash-configuration

Recently I encountered a little white problem when I was learning logstash,I try to transfer data from Kafka to Bigquery

I'm instantiating logstash using -

```
logstash-8.2.3/bin/logstash -f config/logstash-sample.conf
```

Config File

```
input {
  kafka {
        bootstrap_servers => ["addcn102:9092,addcn103:9092,addcn104:9092"]
        group_id => "logstash_kagka"
        auto_offset_reset => "earliest"
        consumer_threads => 3
        topics => ["houstonbq"]
        codec => "json"
  }
}

output {
  google_bigquery {
        project_id => "newcar8891"
        dataset => "logstash"
        json_key_file => "/home/shurui/bin/newcar8891-013ef3777de7.json"
        error_directory => "/opt/module/bqerror"
        flush_interval_secs => "30"
        csv_schema >= "message:STRING"
  }
}
```

This is error log

```
Using bundled JDK: /opt/module/logstash-8.2.3/jdk
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Sending Logstash logs to /opt/module/logstash-8.2.3/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2022-10-21T17:19:07,041][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Log4j configuration path used is: /opt/module/logstash-8.2.3/config/log4j2.properties
[2022-10-21T17:19:07,051][WARN ][logstash.runner          ] The use of JAVA_HOME has been deprecated. Logstash 8.0 and later ignores JAVA_HOME and uses the bundled JDK. Running Logstash with the bundled JDK is recommended. The bundled JDK has been verified to work with each specific version of Logstash, and generally provides best performance and reliability. If you have compelling reasons for using your own JDK (organizational-specific compliance requirements, for example), you can configure LS_JAVA_HOME to use that version instead.
[2022-10-21T17:19:07,052][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"8.2.3", "jruby.version"=>"jruby 9.2.20.1 (2.5.8) 2021-11-30 2a2962fbd1 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.15+10 on 11.0.15+10 +indy +jit [linux-x86_64]"}
[2022-10-21T17:19:07,054][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] JVM bootstrap flags: [-Xms1g, -Xmx1g, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=true, -Djruby.jit.threshold=0, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom, -Dlog4j2.isThreadContextMapInheritable=true, -Djruby.regexp.interruptible=true, -Djdk.io.File.enableADS=true, --add-opens=java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.base/java.nio.channels=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED]
[2022-10-21T17:19:07,349][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[2022-10-21T17:19:08,125][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600, :ssl_enabled=>false}
[2022-10-21T17:19:08,401][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main,
:exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", 
:message=>"Expected one of [ \\t\\r\\n], \"#\", \"=>\" at line 19, column 13 (byte 420) 
after output 
{\n  google_bigquery {\n\t
project_id => \"newcar8891\"\n\t
dataset => \"logstash\"\n\t
csv_schema ",:backtrace=>["/opt/module/logstash-8.2.3/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:32:in `compile_imperative'", 
"org/logstash/execution/AbstractPipelineExt.java:189:in `initialize'",
"org/logstash/execution/JavaBasePipelineExt.java:72:in `initialize'",
"/opt/module/logstash-8.2.3/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:48:in `initialize'",
"/opt/module/logstash-8.2.3/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:50:in `execute'", 
"/opt/module/logstash-8.2.3/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:381:in `block in converge_state'"]}
[2022-10-21T17:19:08,471][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Logstash shut down.
```

This is my kafka data

```
{
    "@timestamp" => 2022-10-21T09:24:51.281353Z,
       "message" => "help me \b",
          "tags" => [
        [0] "_jsonparsefailure"
    ],
      "@version" => "1"
}
```

I want to send the content of the message to bigquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From error message it can be understood that there is a syntax error in your output plugin configuration. Try below output plugin in config.

```
output {
  google_bigquery {
        project_id => "newcar8891"
        dataset => "logstash"
        csv_schema => "message:STRING"
        json_key_file => "/home/shurui/bin/newcar8891-013ef3777de7.json"
        error_directory => "/opt/module/bqerror"
        flush_interval_secs => "30"
  }
}
```